# How do I get a rails template to add additional attributes on migration columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I add things like default values to migrations from an application template.

For example in template.rb:

```
generate(:scaffold, "Thing title:string")
```

What would be the best way to add something like `, :default => 'Foo Bar', :null => false` to the line in the migration that creates the title column.

I have two ideas, but don't know if either is possible.

First, can additional attributes be added to the column from the generator? Can default values be set when the `rails g scaffold` command is called?

Second, could I add a `gsub_file` line after the generate line in my template. I don't know how to do gsub_file on a file where part of the file's name is not known (the timestamp on the migration).

```
Rails-3.1.0
Ruby-1.9.2-p290
```

Comment: There's an [`in_root` method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2a959d8fbe42c2c2cc9e625bf5f52edb9ec0fd84/railties/lib/rails/generators/actions.rb#L212) that might be available, that plus a bit for Dir parsing should give you the migration file's location.

Comment: @muistooshort - make that an answer and I'll accept it. You put me down the right path.

Comment: Sure, I felt I had to say a bit more though.

Comment: Very grateful for your question, @Preacher.  It's just what I need.  That said, the Thor documentation for [`in_root`](http://rdoc.info/github/wycats/thor/Thor/Actions:in_root) is super scanty.  I can't quite understand how I should use mu's answer.  Any hints on what you ultimately did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the help:

```
$ rails generate model --help
Usage:
  rails generate model NAME [field:type field:type] [options]
[...]
```

you won't see any options for specifying anything more than field names and types. AFAIK, you have to edit the generated migration if you want other options.

If you look at [the source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2a959d8fbe42c2c2cc9e625bf5f52edb9ec0fd84/railties/lib/rails/generators/actions.rb#L212), you will see things like this:

```
def generate(what, *args)
  log :generate, what
  argument = args.map {|arg| arg.to_s }.flatten.join(" ")

  in_root { run_ruby_script("script/rails generate #{what} #{argument}", :verbose => false) }
end
```

So maybe you have access to `in_root` (which apparently comes from Thor these days) to put you at the application root so that you can use `Dir['db/migrate/*']` to find the migration file; you presumably know the filename except for the leading timestamp and the part of the filename that you know is unique because it maps to a class name. So, you should be able to find the migration file and then you can patch it up as needed.

Comment: Thanks for this question and to @mu_is_to_short for this answer.  It also got me on the right path though it took me a long time to figure out how to awkwardly apply it.  I'm putting my solution in a separate answer where SO will let me add some code which might help others at my level.

Answer (score 3):

Based on @mu_is_to_short's information, I came up with an inelegant solution that does work.  Feel free to comment on how to clean it up.  In my rails template:

```
generate "migration add_index_to_users_email"
index_migration_array = Dir['db/migrate/*_add_index_to_users_email.rb']
index_migration_file = index_migration_array.first
in_root { insert_into_file index_migration_file, 
  "\n    add_index :users, :email, unique: true", after: "change" }
rake "db:migrate"
```

Thor's documentation on [`in_root`](http://rdoc.info/github/wycats/thor/Thor/Actions%3ain_root) is scanty.  I've got a beginner's knowledge of Dir, etc.  Thank you for this question and answer!  They were what I needed.